# Logs in terminal when running my flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter

```
Launching lib/main.dart on M2004J19PI in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              6.9s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...                 8.4s
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 4256): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
I/flutter ( 4256): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Localization initialized
I/flutter ( 4256): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Start
I/flutter ( 4256): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init state
I/flutter ( 4256): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Build
I/flutter ( 4256): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init Localization Delegate
I/flutter ( 4256): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init provider
I/flutter ( 4256): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Load Localization Delegate
I/flutter ( 4256): [ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Load asset from assets/i18n
Syncing files to device M2004J19PI...                              342ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

 Running with sound null safety 

An Observatory debugger and profiler on M2004J19PI is available at: http://127.0.0.1:37793/tFmjP6B-7Rk=/
I/some.some( 4256): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=1709 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on M2004J19PI is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9102?uri=http://127.0.0.1:37793/tFmjP6B-7Rk=/
W/DynamiteModule( 4256): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 4256): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 4256): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
V/NativeCrypto( 4256): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 294 native methods...
W/some.some( 4256): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller( 4256): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/System.out( 4256): [socket]:check permission begin!
W/some.some( 4256): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/some.some( 4256): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/some.some( 4256): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/some.some( 4256): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/some.some( 4256): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/some.some( 4256): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/GED     ( 4256): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 29, oppidx_max 29, oppidx_min 0
I/GED     ( 4256): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 29, oppidx_max 29, oppidx_min 0
V/PhoneWindow( 4256): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@b032090, this = DecorView@3a0ed89[MainActivity]
```

after adding firebase-related setup I am getting this message in my terminal when running my flutter app. My app works fine but I am unable to understand what are these logs.

are these logs affect my app in the future??

are these logs expected or do I need to do anything to remove these logs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. these logs are for debug mode only and in production mode, these are dismissed. see [assert](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert) for more info.

no, you do not have to do anything. these logs are normal.